# Looking for C++ HTTP Server Lib with chunked encoding handling

Tags: windows, linux, c++, c, http

Do you know any C++/C library for implementing HTTP server that has possibility of "overloading" chunked data handler, i.e. I'd like to have access to chunked data after each chunk. I need compatibility with Windows and Linux.